# MongooseError: You can not `mongoose.connect()` multiple times while connected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting the below error when  trying to connect using moongoose.

MongooseError: You can not `mongoose.connect()` multiple times while connected.

throw new _mongoose.Error('You can not `mongoose.connect()` multiple times while connected.');
    ^
MongooseError: You can not `mongoose.connect()` multiple times while connected.
    at new MongooseError (/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/mongooseError.js:10:11)

Please help me find the cause for this and how to prevent it

Comment: Hi Thomas, welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you post your connection code? It's difficult to figured out what is wrong with just the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mongoose version 5.6.1 the check was added https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/7905

Revert to an older version for a quick fix.

Answer (score 4):

In order to use multiple MongoDB connections use `mongoose.createConnection` function instead of `mongoose.connect`.

`mongoose.createConnection` Will give you a connection object which you can further use in your model file, Cause models are always bound to a single connection

```
let config = require('../config');
let mongoose = require('mongoose');

exports.connect = function () {
  const db = mongoose.createConnection(config.mongoUrl, {
    reconnectInterval: 5000,
    reconnectTries: 60
    // add more config if you need
  });
  db.on(`error`, console.error.bind(console, `connection error:`));
  db.once(`open`, function () {
    // we`re connected!
    console.log(`MongoDB connected on "  ${config.mongoUrl}`);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem and solved pretty easily.
All i had to do was to remove any connections in my controllers.

Before:
Server.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const connectionString = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/DB';
mongoose.connect(connectionString);
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
//Server code...
```

Controller.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const connectionString = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/DB';
mongoose.connect(connectionString);
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
//Controller code...
```

After:
Server.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const connectionString = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/DB';
mongoose.connect(connectionString);
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
//Server code...
```

Controller.js

```
//Controller code...
```

Obviously I removed it from all my controller files.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by 'iamdimitar', the ability to call `mongoose.connect()` more than once was removed in this [PR](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/7905). This is said to be done to prevent errors.

If you must call `mongoose.connect()` more than once, you can use one `mongoose.connect()` and use `mongoose.createConnection()` for the rest. That worked for me (I only used one other `mongoose.createConnection()`)