# Nodejs with koa and Mongo - MongooseError: You can not `mongoose.connect()` multiple times while connected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pm2, koa

I have an application in a aws machine in nodejs with koa and this application connects with a mongodb on a different aws machine. The error I am getting is `MongooseError: You can not`mongoose.connect()`multiple times while connected.` I am also running the application with pm2

this is the code to connect to the db:

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { transform } = require('koa-bootstrap-service/lib/plugins');
const url = require('url');

const config = require('../../config/index');

mongoose.Promise = Promise;

function makeMongoUrl() {
    const dbSettings = config.mongoDb;
    if (!dbSettings) {
        return false;
    }

    if (dbSettings.url) {
        return dbSettings.url;
    }

    const urlObj = {
        hostname: dbSettings.host,
        port: dbSettings.port,
        pathname: `/${dbSettings.db}`,
        query: dbSettings.options,
        protocol: 'mongodb',
        slashes: true,
    };
    if (dbSettings.username) {
        urlObj.auth = `${dbSettings.username}:${dbSettings.password || ''}`;
    }
    return url.format(urlObj);
}

function connectMongoDb() {
    mongoose.plugin(transform.middleware());
    mongoose
        .connect(makeMongoUrl(), {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
            keepAlive: 1,
            connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
            reconnectTries: 30,
        })
        .then(() => {
            global.Logger.debug('Mongoose Connected');
        })
        .catch(({ stack }) => {
            global.Logger.error(stack);
            process.exit(0);
        });
}

connectMongoDb();
```

Comment: Do you import and use the file you are showing in multiple places?

Comment: not really but good thought.

Comment: Connect once when the app starts, not for every request. We don't know how you're using this file in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56760259/11330560

To quote:

> In mongoose version 5.6.1 the check was added https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/7905
>
> Revert to an older version for a quick fix.

---

If in *package.json* the mongoose version is like this: `^5.x.y` then caret `^` will make it update to the recent **minor** version, that is, up to the highest `x` (like `5.9.y` but not `6.x.y`).
So one must force the older version.

---

**UPDATE:** according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56816168/11330560

One must **remove any other connections** in **any controller files**, with only the main file being able to make connection.

Comment: I did not update my version on package.json. The mongoose version I am using is  "mongoose": "^5.3.14" so it should not be a version problem but thanks anyway

Comment: @RicardoParro I noticed something. Doesn't caret `^` indicate it updates you to the most recent minor version?! That is you already using the recent version. Try uninstall and reinstall forcing the older version.(also as far as I know [keepAlive](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#keepAlive) is a boolean, and true by default)

Comment: you are right. thanks so much this fixed it. It was actually a bit more difficult because I am using koa bootstrap service which uses mongoose and the version there was expecting the most recent minor and that broke the code. Awesome! Thanks