# Node Js - Mongoose connect error in Mocha Test code

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mocha.js, chai

In Mocha,  for the below test code, I am getting mongoose connect error.

```
describe('Users', () => {
    before(function (done) {
        process.env.PORT=5001;
        mongoose
            .connect(
                process.env.DB_CONNECTIION_TEST, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
            )
            .then(result => {
                const user = new User({
                    "_id": "6492867bc1b86452fc1b4b8d",
                    "name":"John Doe"
                  });
                return user.save();
            })
            .then(() => {
                done();
            });
    });

    
   
    after(function(done) {
        process.env.PORT=5000;
        User.deleteMany({})
          .then(() => {
            return mongoose.disconnect();
          })
          .then(() => {
            done();
          });
      });

});
```

Error:
error: uncaughtException: Can't call `openUri()` on an active connection with different connection strings. Make sure you aren't calling `mongoose.connect()` multiple times. See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections

In this forum response, It might be fix when we revert to older version.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56760259

```
In mongoose version 5.6.1 the check was added. https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/7905

Revert to an older version for a quick fix.
```

But I feel downgrading to an older version of Mongoose, as suggested in the forum response, may not be the best long-term solution.

Is there anyway to connect mongoose in my test with the latest version?